# On the persistence of links upon deletion of answers

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, linked-questions

Suppose that I answer a question. In my answer, I link to another question or answer on the same Stack Exchange site. Then, I delete my answer.

It seems that, even upon deletion of the answer, the linked question or answer still shows up on the `Linked` sidebar. If this is indeed correct, is this desirable?

Comment: The cache is very long-lived, 30 days (!). If you have example of a linked post that appears even more than 30 days after deletion please add to the question and I'll reopen.